# How to identify Who holds an NFT for how long?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am developing an NFT collection using ERC721 token. But I would like to know how a particular nft is held by a particular customer?

I am sensing there are two selling option one is minting fropm my website another one is buying from opensea?

Is that any way I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

The ERC-721 contract uses this `mapping(uint256 => address) private _owners;` to store the owner. If you want to keep track of how long an address has holded a particular NFT you can create a struct

```
struct Owner {
  address ownerAddress;
  uint256 sinceWhen;
}
```

You then need to modify some functions (like `mint`, `transfer`, ...) and you set the `sinceWhen` as the `block.timestamp`.

Comment: But what  if they sell their nft on opensea, Will my contract able to identify that as well?

Comment: I don't think you really understand how NFTs work. You should try to read the docs and learn more before posting such questions.